# Name for operation returning number of empty elements in set at every depth?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $A=\{1, 2, B\}$ where $B=\{3, 4, C\}$ and $C=\{5, 6\}$. So $A=\{1, 2, \{3, 4, \{5, 6\}\}\}$.

Is there a name for an operation on $A$ that returns the number of empty elements in $A$ at every level of depth, i.e. $E(A)=|\{1, 2\}|+|\{3, 4\}|+|\{5, 6\}|=2+2+2=6$?

Comment: If you would like more 'generally defined' operations you should probably begin by specifying the domain, that is, what kind of elements it acts on.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I've edited the OP to clarify.

Comment: Do you want to know if there is a 'canonical name' for this operation you described? Otherwise, you just defined it (apart from things like specifying $A$, $B$ and $C$).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes, I'm asking if there's a canonical name, like 'union'.

Comment: I don't know of any such name. I don't think it exists, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Number of terminal nodes of a tree?

Comment: @kimchilover Maybe. Thinking of the empty elements as terminal nodes is a nice idea.

Comment: A related concept used in some set theories is stratification.